# using UI-Router based on application state/data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to use Angulars ui-routing based on data conditions? For example, suppose I would need to implement some kind of subscription flow. Eventually, the user gets to see a page telling him that the subscription was either a success or not.

But during the flow, based on data, there are decisions that need to be taken. For example: if the user is already logged on, we need to to know what email address he will use for the subscription and the user gets a view asking him for an email. If not logged on, the user gets a login/registration screen.

It took some research to realize in angular that 'state' is actually a view, so googling state gives me the wrong results. I also encountered [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119476/how-to-route-pages-using-ui-router-based-on-role-and-authentication-in-angularjs)
(which I feel like is a similar case). In a comment there is a link to [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)
but I can't really figure out if that is really what I need.

So, simply put: Can I change the view of a page, using ui-router and based on a data condition, for example:

```
/* this could be set by an ng-init directive */
$scope.isLoggedOn = false;

 ... 

function showView() {
   if $scope.isLoggedOn --- > show the email view
   if not $scope.isLoggedOn --- > show the login/registration view
};
```

*** EDIT ***
Following the answer of Ran Sasportas, i created a Plunker demo. Don't expect too much of it, its very basic, but at least it works. [Here is the link](http://plnkr.co/edit/RnIgPCapq7LTWMjMxB52)
I might add some more features later on, when I am testing nesting views and controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui-router has a service called $state , which you inject to you're controller. That way you can control what views you want to use for example - 
$state.go('login') 
That will trigger the login state you have defined in you're config section .
That's it. You can check out ui routers documentation - http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Good luck.

Comment: This looks promising indeed! If you don't mind, I am going to try this first before I accept the answer :-) .

Comment: looking forward to hear the result.

Comment: This was quite usefull! thank you very much! I have updated my question so now it includes a link to Plunker where I have put something together that resembles what I need.